# Accessing sklearn pipeline from within Transformer/Regressor

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

Is it possible to access the scikit-learn pipeline from within one of the objects that is used in the pipeline. I want to access the `named_steps` attribute of the pipeline inside `Regressor` as illustrated below:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline

class Transform(object):
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        print("Transform.fit")
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        print("Transform.transform")
        return X

class Regressor(object):
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        print("Regressor.fit")
        # Can I get the named_steps attribute from
        # the pipeline that Regressor is part of here

    def predict(self, X):
        print("Regressor.predict")

model = make_pipeline(Transform(), Regressor())
print(model.steps)
print("Begin Fit")
model.fit(1)
print("End Fit")
print("Begin Predict")
model.predict(1)
print("End Predict")
```

The reason I want to do this is to access which transformer is used before the regressor.

EDIT:
To elaborate, I'm writing some custom transformer and regressor objects that I'm using together in a pipeline.

One thing that I'd like to do is have the regressor object change behaviour depending on how many transformer objects that have come before. I could specify it explicitly as a variable when you initialize the regressor class, but ideally I'd like not to.

Second thing that I'd like to do is to enable a regressor to both be used as a transformer and a regressor (I will probably have to override some functionality in the pipeline class). Any regressors coming later in the pipeline would need to change their behaviour if a regressor have been used to transform the data.

Comment: I don't think you can access the pipeline from within one of the steps.
Maybe if you would explain what in you Regressor.fit would use this information, I can help with an alternative

Comment: @shaharA Thank you for the response. See the edit for some more details.

Comment: Why not keep separate pipeline for transformers and then pass that pipeline as a parameter into the regressor. In this you can check the named_steps of the passed pipeline and act accordingly. For the data transformation, you just need to call `pipeline.transform()` and use that in the regressor. Showing the code of what you actually want to do will help.

Comment: @VivekKumar That is a good idea. The problem with this is that I would like to do hyper parameter optimization on the entire pipeline. Passing the pipeline as a variable, or passing the previous transformation as a variable hierarchically would make this somewhat difficult.